# Is it possible to bitbake a layer without without building entire core?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Suppose I create a new layer *meta-example* with a recipe whose provider is *example* that has no dependencies with core (layer *meta*). Suppose the *do_build* task is just an echo. You can replicate this scenario issuing these commands:

```
bitbake-layers create-layer meta-examaple
bitbake-layers add-layer meta-example
```

Is there a way to execute *bitbake example* without having to build the entire core?

I tried to set LAYERDEPENDS_meta-example = "" (previously it was set to core) but in vain. I would have expected the echo command to be executed without the entire core build process.

I cannot manage to find where Yocto is programmed to build the core before any other layer. Where can I find this piece of code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

At no point is "the entire core" built unless you bitbake `world` or `universe`.  Building a recipe will build gcc, binutils, glibc and so on, but that's not all of oe-core.

Comment: Isn't there a way to avoid building the toolchain if my recipe does not need it? Where is this dependency implicitly defined?

Comment: You probably need to inherit allarch class, as that's what used for recipes that provide scripts or arch-independent data.